# Angular two-way binding

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an `Angular` directive, which reads in the contents of a file `<input>` and populates a form. Currently, it seems to update the `$scope` variables within the controller, but the form elements bound to those `$scope` variables are not being updated in the view. Why is this?

The code snippets below are as follows:

1. my directive, which i use to read in from a file `<input>` and call the controller's `$scope['modify_form']`, which allows me to update the `$scope` variables corresponding to my form.
2. the HTML (view-side) for my directive
3. my controller logic for `$scope['modify_form']`, which calls a bunch of helper functions, one of which is shown below.
4. a snippet of the `HTML` of my view for my form; this is where the fundamental problem lies, since it does not get updated when i call `$scope['modify_form']`

Here is my directive, for reading in content:

```js
app.directive('modifyBtn', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            modifyJSON:'&modifyJson',
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            var fileElem = angular.element(element.find("#file_input2"));
            console.log(fileElem);

            var showUpload = function() {
                // display file input element
                var file = fileElem[0].files[0];
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.readAsText(file);

                reader.onload = function(e) {
                        var uploadedJSON;

                        try {
                            uploadedJSON = JSON.parse(reader.result);
                        } catch(e) {
                            // should display help block (or warning)
                            return;
                        }

                        console.log(uploadedJSON); // @debug

                        for (var key in uploadedJSON) { // only one key
                            if (uploadedJSON.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                                sessionStorage[MODEL] = key;
                                sessionStorage[NAMESPACE] = uploadedJSON[key][NAMESPACE]

                                var fields = [FIELDS, LINKS, PRIMARY_KEY, TABLE, SQL, VALIDATIONS];

                                fields.forEach(function(field) {
                                    if (uploadedJSON[key].hasOwnProperty(field)) {
                                        sessionStorage[field] = JSON.stringify(uploadedJSON[key][field]);
                                    }
                                });

                                // trigger modification without reloading page
                                scope.modifyJSON();
                            }
                        }
                }

            };
            $(fileElem).on('change', showUpload);
        }
    }
});
```

My view (`HTML`), for the *directive* is as follows:

```html
<modify-btn modify-json="modifyForm()">
    <li class="active">
        <span class="btn creation-btn" style="background-color: #d9534f;" ng-click="fileshow = true">
            Upload JSON
        </span>
    </li>
    <li><input type="file" id="file_input2" ng-show="fileshow" /></li>
</modify-btn>
```

In my controller, here is where I update the `$scope` variables bound to the form:

```js
$scope['modifyForm'] = function() { // filling in elements if reading in JSON

    modify_data();
    modify_fields();
    modify_links();
    modify_pkeys();
    modify_table();
    modify_sql();
    modify_validations();

    sessionStorage.clear();

}

function modify_data() {

    var overall = [MODEL, NAMESPACE];

    overall.forEach(function(elem) {
        if (exist(sessionStorage[elem])) {
            $scope['data'][elem] = sessionStorage[elem];
        }
    });
}
```

And, here, in the view is how my form elements are bound.

```html
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4">{{myConstants["model"]}}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="data[myConstants['model']]" id="model" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4">{{myConstants["namespace"]}}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="data[myConstants['namespace']]" id="namespace" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your doing some clever and sneaky things here Noah, and I like that.

Comment: I know this sounds weird, but you should look at your DOM Elements through the Developers Console (I suggest using Chrome for it). You will see you `ng-model` attribute written out on your element the way that Angular interpreted it. You should make sure that Angular did not choke trying to evaluate the values that you provided by `ng-model`, you could possibly even see `data['undefined']` as your `ng-model` but I have no guarantees there. If you can, take a screen shot of what these elements look like through the Developers Console and include it here.

Comment: I admit I haven't read all your code. Maybe `$scope.$apply()` is missing in your `modifyForm` function? Just a feeling...

Comment: As I can see you read a file so it may be something like synchronization problem with scope. I would use $q service in that case. The best thing to do is to log (_$log or console.log, info, console.dir...._) as much as possible to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Btw it is really interesting, I'm impatient you tell us how you resolved.